# Comparar carácter por carácter en JAVA

Tags: java

Necesito leer carácter por carácter el texto ingresado por un usuario y compararlo con palabras predeterminadas.

Yo he pensado algo como:

```
for (int i=0;tamPalabra;i++)
{
  if (palabraPredeterminada.charAt(i) == palabraIngresada.charAt(i)) 
  {
    System.out.println("La palabra es la misma");
  }
}
```

Comment: Buenas Daniel, bienvenido a [es.so]. Si te pasas por el [Tour] y [ask] podrás aprender más de este sitio y como hacer preguntas de calidad. Una pregunta del tipo "cual es la mejor" se considera basada en opiniones y la de "un ejemplo de como se podria implementar" es muy amplio. Te sujiero que trates tú de implementarlo y cuando tengas una duda concreta o un error, preguntarlo aqui con la explicacion y ejemplos. Un saludo

Comment: Creo recordar que puedes coger la longitud de un string en java, y con el metodo `CharAt()` sacar el caracter de dicha posicion. no lo pongo como respuesta porque no se si seria valida.

Comment: POSDATA: si la pregunta no es clara, la respuesta tampoco lo sera XD

Comment: Ya la reformule. Ya es mas entendible?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en Java ya existe el método `equals` y `equalsIgnoreCase` que devuelven *`true`* o *`false`* dependiendo si coinciden o no

Comment: Eso que tienes no sirve por que con que tenga un carácter en común va a imprimir que las palabras son iguales.

Comment: Quieres comparar una palabra ingresada con palabras predeterminadas para saber si coinciden?

Comment: @FrEqDe Sí. Tengo que comprar.

Comment: Sigue sin entenderse, estaría bueno que pongas ejemplos de cadenas ya comparadas para ver qué está bien y qué no.

Comment: ¿Cual es la razón de que sea caracter por caracter?

Answer (score 1):

## Usando equals

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
for(int i=0;i<palabras_predeterminadas.length;i++)
if(palabras_predeterminadas[i].equals(palabra_ingresada))
System.out.println("La palabra Ingresada es igual a"+palabras_predeterminadas[i]) ;
```

`palabras_predeterminadas` es un arreglo que contiene las palabras predeterminadas de tu programa, y `palabra_ingresada` es la palabra que lees desde el teclado.

## Comparando carácter por carácter

```
public static boolean comparar(String p1, String p2){
if(p1.length()==p2.length()){
for(int i=0;i<p1.length();i++)
if(p1.charAt(i)!=p2.charAt(i))
return false;
return true;
}

return false;
}
```

### Usando el método comparar:

```
for(int i=0;i<palabras_predeterminadas.length;i++)
if(comparar(palabras_predeterminadas[i],palabra_ingresada))
System.out.println("La palabra Ingresada es igual a"+palabras_predeterminadas[i]) ;
```

Comment: Al parecer el OP especifica que **sea carácter por carácter.**

Comment: @Dev.Joel tienes razón, he agregado una opción para comparar carácter por carácter.

Comment: @Recordar que cuando el `for` lleva más de dos líneas de código dentro de él es importante utilizar `{.. }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 //declaramos la palabra predeterminada
    String predeterminada = "hola";

    //declaramos una palabra de entrada
    String entrada = "hola";

    //variable usada para verificar si las palabras son iguales
    String aux="";

    //se verifica que ambas palabras tengan la misma longitud
    //si no es asi no se pueden comparar
    if(predeterminada.length()==entrada.length()){

        for(int i=0;i<predeterminada.length();i++){

            //verificamos si el primer caracter de predeterminada
            //es igual al primero de entrada
           if(predeterminada.charAt(i)==entrada.charAt(i)){
               //si es asi guardamos ese concatenamos el caracter a la variable aux
               aux+=predeterminada.charAt(i);
           }
        }

        //al finalizar el bucle verificamos si la variable aux es
        //igual a la predeterminada
        if(aux.equals(predeterminada)){
            System.out.println("son iguales");
        }else{
            System.out.println("no son iguales");
        }



    }else{
        System.out.println("las palabras no tienen la misma longitud");
    }
```